# Burger's equation (PDE) does not work with step function?

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods, pde

I'm working on implementing the *discretised Burger's equation*. I am quite confused as to why it does not work with when using a *step-function*. When using a step-function, I am getting a `singular matrix error` but when using something else such as `v = 0.4 + 0.2 * np.exp(-40 * (x - 0.5)**2)`, in the initial data function I do not.

The step function should provide results but I'm unable to identify where or why it's going wrong. I'm trying to run it with

- viscosity value `ν = 0.01`
- time-step `t = 0.01`
- grid size `h = 0.01`
- and final time `T = 1`.

The initial solution `u(x, 0)` is taken as a unit step at `x = 0.1`, boundary conditions as: `u(0, t) = 1` and `u(1, t) = 0`.

Quite new to Python and notebook, would greatly appreciate insights into where I am going wrong.

I've provided a reproducible example: [burgers.py](https://pastebin.com/BPZVTsqc)

This is how I'm implementing the *discretised Burger's equation*:

```
def DiscretisedBurgers(uk, ukp, dt, h, nu, ua, ub):

    # ua is boundary condition
    # ub is boundary condition 
    # nu is kinematic viscosity 
    m = ukp.size
    # f to store values of the function for each point uk in space
    f = np.zeros((m-2, 1))

    # boundary conditions
    uL = ua
    uR = ub

    # left boundary
    f[0] = (uk[0] - ukp[1])/dt + uk[0] * (uk[0] - uL)/h - nu * (uk[1] - 2*uk[0] + uL)/h**2

    # Difference equations at each internal node
    for i in range(1, m-3):
        f[i] = (uk[i] - ukp[i+1])/dt + uk[i] * (uk[i] - uk[i-1])/h - nu * (uk[i+1] - 2*uk[i] + uk[i-1])/h**2

    # Difference equation at the right boundary
    f[m-3] = (uk[m-3] - ukp[m-2])/dt + uk[m-3] * (uk[m-3] - uk[m-4])/h - nu * (uR - 2*uk[m-3] + uk[m-4])/h**2

    return f
```

Initial data set up:

```
def initialData(m):

    # Input: grid size m
    # Output: initial condition u
    
    # spatial domain endpoints
    xL = 0
    xR = 1
    
    h = (xR - xL) / (m-1)                      # mesh size
    x = np.linspace(xL, xR, m).reshape((m, 1)) # grid points
    v = np.zeros(len(x))

    v = my_step_function(x) # initial data
    
    # Boundary conditions
    uL = v[0]
    uR = v[m-1]
    
    return v
```

Comment: What would you like the derivative to be at the step?

Comment: @lastchance Thanks for the reply! im not sure what you mean, are you referring to the order of the derivative?

Comment: You are at a point where you have to chose between qualitatively correct results of low order, or a higher order method with no result or a very unstable result that in the end is also qualitatively incorrect. The best approach for the first are finite-volume schemes, In finite differences the support of the difference formula plays a critical role. There are named methods for especially successful approaches, see https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+lax+burger%27s, https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=upwind+burger%27s